# Javascript object key as variable

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
let object1 = { a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' };
```

I'm trying to set object1.a to be a key for object2:

```
object2 = { key: 'something' };
```

I tried to make key as:

```
[object1].a

object1.a

object1[a]
```

I remember I have to use bracket notation but can't figure out how to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm going to change the values of object1 depending on props so I can just have a single component that changes key based on prop received.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: `object1.a = object2`?

Comment: object1['a'] = ""; you can use it like this

Comment: `object2['a'] = object1['a']`

Comment: `object2[object1.a] = something;`

Comment: *"...I'm going to change the values of object1 depending on props so I can just have a single component that changes key based on prop received."* What do you mean by that? Do you mean you want `object1.a = "updated"` to also update `object2`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So I tried object2 = { object1['a']: 'something' } as well, but it's not working...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I'm making a component for ReactJS. Making it generalized so I can just pass a string prop for object1.a which equals object2.a

Comment: @cocacrave: But I mean, after that, if something assigns to `object1.a`, you're not expecting `object2` to change at all, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `object2` already exists, you just use brackets notation:

```
object2[object1.a] = 'something';
```

Now, `object2` has a property called `one` that has the value `'something'`.

If you're *creating* object2, in ES5 you have to create the object separately first, and then add the property:

```
var object2 = {};
object2[object1.a] = 'something';
```

In ES2015 ("ES6"), you can use a *computed* property name in the initializer (note the `[]`):

```
// ES2015 only!
let object2 = {
    [object1.a]: 'something'
};
```

Just as with bracket notation when you're doing assignment, you can have any expression within those brackets in the initializer.

Note that this does *not* create ongoing link between the objects. It purely evaluates the value of `object1.a` at the moment the initializer is processed, and uses the resulting value as the name of the new property on the new object.

Comment: Thanks, this works :) I didn't know you can use dot notation inside bracket notation.

Comment: @cocacrave - You can put any expression inside the square brackets, e.g., it's quite legal to say something like `object2[condition ? "test" : callFunc() + object1.a + "another string"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the // ES2015 only! tip :)